# While Loop Repeating forever when printing statement

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am making a Hangman Game where the user guesses a color. What I want to happen is: If the user gets more than 5 incorrectly, (went through all 5 hints), it will state that the user lost. After the while loop finishes (the word is correct or went through all 5 hints) it should tell you whether you won or not.
This is the part of the code that does that:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String color = getColor();
  String result = EmptyStr(color);
  String[] hints = getHints(color);
  System.out.println("Please enter a letter:");
  char letter = in.next().charAt(0);
//-----------------------------------------------------------
  int wrong = 0;
  while (wrong<6){
    if (checkLetter(color, letter)){
      // result was previously defined elsewhere so don't worry about it
      result = Result(color, result, letter);
      System.out.println("Correct guess! here is your word so far: " + result);
      System.out.println("Lifelines left: " + (5 - wrong));
      if (result.equals(color)){
        System.out.println("congratulations! You Won!");
        break;
      }
    }
    else{
      wrong ++;
      System.out.println(hints[0]);
      System.out.println("Lifelines left: " + (5 - wrong));
    }
  }
  // also not sure what to put here after player wins or loses: System.out.println("Sorry! You lost! The correct word was: " + color);
```

}

However, once I input one letter, and it is correct,
    `result = Result(color, result, letter);
    System.out.println("Correct guess! here is your word so far: " + result);
    System.out.println("Lifelines left: " + (5 - wrong));`
repeats forever. I want to know: why does it repeat forever? and also, how can I fix it for it to work?

Comment: Assuming that `checkLetter` returns `true` it will only `break` when `result` equals `color` - if not it will loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat But I cannot even re-input another character to check if that is a character in the color

Comment: In that case you need to sort **your** logic out.  Maybe you want to move `char letter = in.next().charAt(0);` into your loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, I realized that after moving it around! Thanks for telling me though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own problem!

The thing is, in order for it to reiterate and allow me to re-enter a letter,
    
 `char letter = in.next().charAt(0);`
must be INSIDE the `while` loop. That fixed the whole problem!

Answer (score -1):

I think I see the issue. You don't have an iteration for when the user gets the guess right, only when the get it wrong. Make sure to add another "wrong ++", in that first if. That might solve the problem.

```
if (checkLetter(color, letter)){
      // result was previously defined elsewhere so don't worry about it
      result = Result(color, result, letter);
      System.out.println("Correct guess! here is your word so far: " + result);
      System.out.println("Lifelines left: " + (5 - wrong));
      wrong ++;
```